# Set min-height of text to height of biggest text without using JS

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list `<ul>` with mulitpile `<li>`.

[image]

As you can see the orange button is not always aligned with the rest. It should look like this:

[image]

The container of the text has the class `crosssell-product-name`.

How can I set the `min-height` to the item with the biggest text (the first one ofc...) withouth using javascript?

I also tried to apply `height: auto !important` on `.crosssell-product-name` but that was not working.

Alternative solutions not requiring JS are welcome too. Thx!

HTML (click on full view):

```css
.item {
    width: 285px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="crosssell-products products-grid flexslider large-icons" id="crosssell-products-list">
    <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
        <ul class="slides last odd" style="width: 800%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <li class="item">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                        <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                        <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                        <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                            <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA AAA</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="actions clearfix">
                            <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                        <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                        <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                        <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                            <a href="">AAAAA AAAAA</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="actions clearfix">
                            <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                        <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                        <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                        <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                            <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="actions clearfix">
                            <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                        <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                        <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                        <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                            <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="actions clearfix">
                            <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use flexbox in css

Comment: @BearNithi, how exactly?

Comment: You can achieve the layout you want by using Flexbox or CSS Grid. There are loads of tutorials and guides if you do a quick search. MDN is a great starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Any hints why there are so many downvotes?

Comment: Probably because it's quite easy to find the solution elsewhere and it's been asked on here a lot. Just a guess...

Comment: @AlxTheRed, then why is it not marked as duplicate question yet? I was not finding the question elsewhere

Comment: Many similar questions can be found by searching for your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+boxes

Comment: @AlxTheRed, every question is specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First :**

Add `display: flex;` on your `<ul>`.

**Second :**

On your class `.actions`, add a `position: absolute;` with `bottom: -10px;`.

---

I hope it will help you

```css
.item {
      width: 285px;
      float: left;
      display: block;
  }
    
  .slides {
      display: flex;
  }

  .actions {

      position: absolute;
      bottom: -10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="crosssell-products products-grid flexslider large-icons" id="crosssell-products-list">
        <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
            <ul class="slides last odd" style="width: 800%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                            <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                            <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                            <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                                <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA AAA</a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="actions clearfix">
                                <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                            <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                            <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                            <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                                <a href="">AAAAA AAAAA</a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="actions clearfix">
                                <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                            <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                            <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                            <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                                <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA</a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="actions clearfix">
                                <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="crosssell-product-image">
                            <a href=""><img alt="..." src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x285"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="crosssell-product-shop">
                            <div class="reviews-wrap"></div>
                            <h3 class="crosssell-product-name">
                                <a href="">AAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA</a>
                            </h3>
                            <div class="actions clearfix">
                                <button class="button btn-cart" type="button">In den Warenkorb</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works, Thx! I used `bottom: -10px` though otherwise the text is to near at the button

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css to streth the items based on other items height. `align-items: stretch` will stretch the elements height based on the other element.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/bearnithi/pen/zeyXvX

Comment: I tried it and it only shows one item and it looks very stretched

Comment: Yes it will get stretched, otherwise you have to set fixed height for you images.